# SystemSoundID Stopping Sounds

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, system-sounds, crash

In my application, I have buttons setup as a keyboard. Each buttons acts similar to a piano key, where you touch the button and the sound plays when you hold but stops when you release. For this method, I am using two IBActions. One for Touch Down (Sound Play) and Touch Up Inside (Sound Stop). I am using SystemSoundID for playing the sounds, as AVAudioPlayer has a delayed play. The only problem is, when I hold down the button the sound plays fine, but once I release the touch my app crashes. Below is my Code:

.h File:

```
SystemSoundID *soundID;
```

.m File:

```
- (IBAction)ASoundStart:(id)sender { 
     NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"P1:4t" ofType:@"mp3"];
     AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], &soundID);
     AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
     [soundFile release];
 }

 - (IBAction)ASoundStop:(id)sender {
     AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
 }
```

Comment: I actually do not have ARC incorporated into my Project. Any way to stop the sound and prevent my App crashing? Why exactly _is_ my app crashing anyway?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're treating SystemSoundID incorrectly as an object. It's simply an integer.

If you take a look at the declaration of AudioServicesPlaySystemSound, notice that it's argument is `SystemSoundID` and not `SystemSoundID *`

```
void AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (
   SystemSoundID inSystemSoundID
);
```

So if you just change `SystemSoundID *soundID` in your header to `SystemSoundID soundID` I believe it should work.

Happy coding.